# How to run a final 'print' statement once in a multi-step map-reduce program?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, collaborative-filtering, mrjob

I am basically trying to implement a recommender system by scaling it up on Hadoop.

In the first step, I am trying to calculate the similarity between every pair of items in the input file.If I store it simply as

{Item A,Item B,Similarity}

the output file size becomes very very large ( for 60kb input i am getting an output file size of 6mb).

Therefore I thought whether it will be better to store the result in python dict and print the dict ONLY ONCE after the end of the entire map reduce program.I am unsuccessful in doing this Please help me.

My python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from math import sqrt

from itertools import combinations

PRIOR_COUNT = 10

PRIOR_CORRELATION = 0

    prefs={}

    def correlation(size, dot_product, rating_sum, \
        rating2sum, rating_norm_squared, rating2_norm_squared):
'''
  The correlation between two vectors A, B is
      [n * dotProduct(A, B) - sum(A) * sum(B)] /
    sqrt{ [n * norm(A)^2 - sum(A)^2] [n * norm(B)^2 - sum(B)^2] }

'''
numerator = size * dot_product - rating_sum * rating2sum
denominator = sqrt(size * rating_norm_squared - rating_sum * rating_sum) * \
                sqrt(size * rating2_norm_squared - rating2sum * rating2sum)

return (numerator / (float(denominator))) if denominator else 0.0


def regularized_correlation(size, dot_product, rating_sum, \
        rating2sum, rating_norm_squared, rating2_norm_squared,
        virtual_cont, prior_correlation):
    '''
    The Regularized Correlation between two vectors A, B

    RegularizedCorrelation = w * ActualCorrelation + (1 - w) * PriorCorrelation
        where w = # actualPairs / (# actualPairs + # virtualPairs).
    '''
    unregularizedCorrelation = correlation(size, dot_product, rating_sum, \
            rating2sum, rating_norm_squared, rating2_norm_squared)

    w = size / float(size + virtual_cont)

    return w * unregularizedCorrelation + (1.0 - w) * prior_correlation

class SemicolonValueProtocol(object):

  # don't need to implement read() since we aren't using it

  def write(self, key, values):
      return ';'.join(str(v) for v in values)

class BooksSimilarities(MRJob):

#OUTPUT_PROTOCOL = SemicolonValueProtocol

def steps(self):
    return [
        self.mr(mapper=self.group_by_user_rating,
                reducer=self.count_ratings_users_freq),
        self.mr(mapper=self.pairwise_items,
                reducer=self.calculate_similarity),
        self.mr(mapper=self.calculate_ranking,
                reducer=self.top_similar_items)]

def group_by_user_rating(self, key, line):
    '''
    Emit the user_id and group by their ratings (item and rating)

    17  70,3
    35  21,1
    49  19,2
    49  21,1
    49  70,4
    87  19,1
    87  21,2
    98  19,2

    '''
    line=line.replace("\"","");
    user_id, item_id, rating = line.split(',')

    yield  user_id, (item_id, float(rating))

def count_ratings_users_freq(self, user_id, values):
    '''
    For each user, emit a row containing their "postings"
    (item,rating pairs)
    Also emit user rating sum and count for use later steps.

    17    1,3,(70,3)
    35    1,1,(21,1)
    49    3,7,(19,2 21,1 70,4)
    87    2,3,(19,1 21,2)
    98    1,2,(19,2)

    '''
    item_count = 0
    item_sum = 0
    final = []
    for item_id, rating in values:
        item_count += 1
        item_sum += rating
        final.append((item_id, rating))

    yield user_id, (item_count, item_sum, final)

def pairwise_items(self, user_id, values):
    '''
    The output drops the user from the key entirely, instead it emits
    the pair of items as the key:

    19,21  2,1
    19,70  2,4
    21,70  1,4
    19,21  1,2

    '''
    item_count, item_sum, ratings = values
    for item1, item2 in combinations(ratings, 2):
        yield (item1[0], item2[0]), (item1[1], item2[1])

def calculate_similarity(self, pair_key, lines):
    '''
    Sum components of each corating pair across all users who rated both
    item x and item y, then calculate pairwise pearson similarity and
    corating counts.  The similarities are normalized to the [0,1] scale
    because we do a numerical sort.

    19,21   0.4,2
    21,19   0.4,2
    19,70   0.6,1
    70,19   0.6,1
    21,70   0.1,1
    70,21   0.1,1

    '''
    sum_xx, sum_xy, sum_yy, sum_x, sum_y, n = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0)
    item_pair, co_ratings = pair_key, lines
    item_xname, item_yname = item_pair
    for item_x, item_y in lines:
        sum_xy += item_x * item_y
        sum_y += item_y
        sum_x += item_x
        sum_xx += item_x * item_x
        sum_yy += item_y * item_y
        n += 1

    reg_corr_sim = regularized_correlation(n, sum_xy, sum_x, \
            sum_y, sum_xx, sum_yy, PRIOR_COUNT, PRIOR_CORRELATION)

    yield (item_xname, item_yname), (reg_corr_sim, n)


def calculate_ranking(self, item_keys, values):
    '''
    Emit items with similarity in key for ranking:

    19,0.4    70,1
    19,0.6    21,2
    21,0.6    19,2
    21,0.9    70,1
    70,0.4    19,1
    70,0.9    21,1

    '''
    reg_corr_sim, n = values
    item_x, item_y = item_keys
    if int(n) > 0:
        yield (item_x, reg_corr_sim),(item_y, n)

def top_similar_items(self, key_sim, similar_ns):
    '''
    For each item emit K closest items in comma separated file:

    De La Soul;A Tribe Called Quest;0.6;1
    De La Soul;2Pac;0.4;2

    '''
    item_x, reg_corr_sim = key_sim
    for item_y, n in similar_ns:
           #yield None, (item_x, item_y, reg_corr_sim, n)
       prefs.setdefault(item_x,{})
       prefs[item_x][item_y] = float(reg_corr_sim)
       prefs.setdefault(item_y,{})
       prefs[item_y][item_x] = float(reg_corr_sim) 
    print "exiting"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   BooksSimilarities.run()
```

So what I want after executing

python thisfile.py < input.csv -r hadoop > output.txt

is a relatively small output file with no repetitions and one dict.

In short,

Currently this program prints **exiting** n times but i want it to print only ONCE.

Apart from all this is there any better way to implement the collaborative filtering by scaling up on hadoop in a better manner.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  I'm guessing you don't actually care about printing "exiting", and if you state what you actually want there's a better chance of getting help.

Answer (score 0):

You only have the guarantee that the values ​​with the same key will go to the same reducer. So if you are running on your cluster multiple reducers, the work is divided and you will have many "exiting" as reducers run to complete the task on all your keys.

Try to run in local and validate if its working:
python thisfile.py < input.csv > output.txt

Maybe you can define a "reducer_final" in your steps() to get all the last step reducer output and manage like you want.

Check: http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/job.html#mrjob.job.MRJob.steps

Kind regards,

Comment: I tried it in local only it prints exiting n times!Also I read up that link you sent me before posting the Question but that always throws up Value Error.

Comment: If possible could anyone please tell me where and what EXACTLY the required changes are such that **reducer_final** works.Thanks.

Comment: I dont know what you really want but if you only want to print the "ending" at the end, then modify the `self.mr(mapper=self.calculate_ranking,
                reducer=self.top_similar_items)` with a `self.mr(mapper=self.calculate_ranking,
                reducer=self.top_similar_items,  reducer_final=self.final_reducer)`  And then add a final_reducer method with the `print`statement. I didnt tested it but is what i understand from the mrjob manual.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want...to print it once ... but when I do what u said def final_reducer (self): print prefs .... it gets printed twice always irrespective of the size of the input. .is it supposed to get called twice.? Thanks.

Comment: @ ACortes Any idea?I really need to get this working.My input data is huge of the size of 1GB.